# Calculate mean and add in new row in R but to reflect in all the entries of a particular column

Tags: r, mean, split-apply-combine

I have the dataset like below,and I read it as a csv file and load the dataframe as **df**

```
Name   Value1 Value1    
A       2       5       
A       1       5       
B       3       4       
B       1       4       
C       0       3       
C       5       3       
C       1       3
```

If I do the following command in R,

```
out<-ddply(df, .(Name), summarize,  Value1=mean(Value1),Value2=mean(Value2))
```

I am getting an output like this,

```
Name   Value1_mean   Value2_mean    
A       1.5             5       
B       2               4       
C       2               3
```

But need to find the mean for **Value2** and **Value1** and store the result in a separate column say **value1_mean** and **value2_mean** like this for every entry,

```
Name   Value1 Value1   value1_mean  value2_mean
A       2       5       1.5           5
A       1       5       1.5           5
B       3       4       2             4
B       1       4       2             4
C       0       3       2             3
C       5       3       2             3
C       1       3       2             3
```

How can I get this above output?

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of `summarize`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this efficiently with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Name', specify the columns to take the `mean` with `.SDcols`, loop through the subset of data.table (`.SD`), get the `mean` and assign (`:=`) it to new columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0(names(df)[2:3], "_mean") := lapply(.SD, mean), by = Name, .SDcols = 2:3]
df
#    Name Value1 Value2 Value1_mean Value2_mean
#1:    A      2      5         1.5           5
#2:    A      1      5         1.5           5
#3:    B      3      4         2.0           4
#4:    B      1      4         2.0           4
#5:    C      0      3         2.0           3
#6:    C      5      3         2.0           3
#7:    C      1      3         2.0           3
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we use `mutate_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(Mean = mean)) 
#    Name Value1 Value2 Value1_Mean Value2_Mean
#  <chr>  <int>  <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     A      2      5         1.5           5
#2     A      1      5         1.5           5
#3     B      3      4         2.0           4
#4     B      1      4         2.0           4
#5     C      0      3         2.0           3
#6     C      5      3         2.0           3
#7     C      1      3         2.0           3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), Value1 = c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L), Value2 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L
)), .Names = c("Name", "Value1", "Value2"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun. It works. Thank you for you help